# SQL Multiple subquery issue

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

Currently struggling with a second subquery (t3) which is giving me a syntax error. The query works fine if t3 is excluded.

```
SELECT switch(LEFT(t1.[treatment],1)='C',"Complaint",LEFT(t1.[treatment],1)='P',"Post") AS Treatment, count(t1.[ID]) AS Total_Vol, count(t2.[event]) AS Total_Posted, format(count(t2.[event]) / count(t1.[ID]),"0.00%") AS Percentage, COUNT(IIF(t1.[requirements]='1',1,)) AS Special _Population,count(t3.[approved]) as Approved_vol
FROM Main_audit_table_v3 AS t1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT t2.[ID], t2.[event] FROM Main _table AS t2 WHERE t2.event Not Like ('NA'))  AS t2 ON t1.[ID] = t2.[ID]
LEFT JOIN (SELECT t3.[ref],t3.[requirement],t3.[approved] from Main_table AS t3 where 
t3.[requirement] = '1' and t3.[approved] not like ('NA')) as t3
t2.[ID] = t3.[ID]
GROUP BY LEFT(t1.[treatment],1);
```

The expected output is that the [approved] column will provide a count of records where requirement = 1 and approved not like NA.

Comment: you have 2 lots of "as t3" and the last 2 lines are disconnected

Comment: .. you have a space between  Main _table ...

Answer (score 0):

In MS Access you need additional parentheses for `JOIN`s.  And you are missing `ON`:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM (Main_audit_table_v3 AS t1 LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT t2.[ID], t2.[event]
       FROM Main _table AS t2
       WHERE t2.event Not Like ('NA')
      ) AS t2 ON t1.[ID] = t2.[ID]
     ) LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT t3.[ref], t3.[requirement], t3.[approved] 
      FROM Main_table AS t3 
      WHERE t3.[requirement] = '1' and t3.[approved] not like 'NA'
     ) as t3
     ON t2.[ID] = t3.[ID]
GROUP BY LEFT(t1.[treatment], 1);
```